# I need to reverse a range of data.

Tags: arithmetic

I have a range of data that goes from 1-10 with 10 being the worst score and 1 being the best score. I want to reverse the range such that 1 is the worst score and 10 is the best. Is there an easy and straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: $y = -(x-11) $?

Comment: perfect. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace $n$ with $11-n$.